# NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS with document.write

Tags: javascript, function, document.write, script-tag

I'm pulling in a 3rd party JavaScript file which makes use of `document.write`, but what's being written needs to be manipulated - preferably before it hits the page.  What I've come up with is the following:

```
// Hijack document.write to buffer all output...
var dwrite = document.write;
var hijacked = '';
document.write = function(content) {
  hijacked += content;
};
// Call the script...
dwrite("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.example.com/file.js'></script>");
// Manipulate the output...
hijacked
  .replace(/a/gi, '4')
  .replace(/e/gi, '3')
  .replace(/i/gi, '1')
  .replace(/o/gi, '0');
// Write the output into the page...
dwrite(hijacked);
// Restore document.write and free our buffer...
document.write = dwrite;
hijacked = null;
```

With this, I'm getting NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS wherever I attempt to call `dwrite`.  Can anyone offer a suggestion on why this is happening?  I don't see why calling document.write through a different name would blow up.

**UPDATE** I'm seeing this in Firefox 4.0.1.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this and it worked.  Basically I replaced *document.write* **after** using it.

```
document.write(""
  + "<script>"
  + "var hijacked = '';"
  + "var dw = document.write;"
  + "document.write = function(content) { hijacked += content; }"
  + "<" + "/script>"

  + "<script type='text/javascript' src='test.js'><" + "/script>"

  + "<script>"
  + "document.write = dw;"
  + "dw = null;"
  + "document.write(hijacked.replace(/e/gi, '4'));"
  + "<" + "/script>");
```

Comment: In which browser(s) did you test?  Should have mentioned that in my post.

Comment: I tried it this way - moving the post-processing logic into it's own script tag after the call to the .js file, and it seemed to do the trick.  Good call - I think the transformative code was running before the external .js was fully processed.